# java swing : using getLayeredPane as parameter or not

Tags: java, swing

i don't understand why we use `getLayeredPane()` before setting the contentPane, in this example :

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("RootLayeredPaneDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    RootLayeredPaneDemo newContentPane = new RootLayeredPaneDemo(
      frame.getLayeredPane());
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 350));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

and then in the constructor we just re-use it (`layeredPane`) :

```
public RootLayeredPaneDemo(JLayeredPane layeredPane)    {
        super(new GridLayout(1,1));

        //Create and set up the layered pane.
        this.layeredPane = layeredPane;
```

But in another example, we just forget the parameter, for example (`new LayeredPaneDemo()`):

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    //Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayeredPaneDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //Create and set up the content pane.
    JComponent newContentPane = new LayeredPaneDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    //Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

and the constructor :

```
public LayeredPaneDemo()    {
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    //Create and set up the layered pane.
    layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the first example refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#layeredpane
and the seconde one refer to : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html

and the answer is told in the first ref. :

***(This) is a version of LayeredPaneDemo that uses the root pane's layered pane, rather than creating a new layered pane***

RootPane are used to manage layers using their references instead of creating new layer... quite clear I think.

Comment: thanks alain.janinm, not so clear to me, when `getLayeredPane() ` is a better choice than creating a new one?

Comment: It depends on your needs, if you see you often need to re-create the same layerpane, or use them somewhere else, then using rootpane can be a better way to manage your panes and improve performance.

Comment: one thing though : when we create an instance of the layeredPane in the 1st ref, we then put it into the content pane, so there is a layered pane by default that contains a content pane, and this content pane contains an instance of our own `layeredpane`, is that correct? thanks

Comment: yes except it's a reference of your own layeredpane not an "instance".

Comment: yeah, i meant the 2nd ref sorry, the 1st one is a reference, the 2nd is an instance, so : either we use the layer pane by default, and what we write into the `content pane` will be in the "background" (behind the layered pane's content, in the most-bottom level), either we create an instance of `JLayeredPane` that we put in the content pane, which is located in the layered pane by default, but the layers stuff will be located in the content pane, not the layer pane by default, is that correct? thanks

Comment: If I don't misunderstand, I'll say yes!The JLayeredPane created is put in the content pane and referenced by the inner layer pane.

Comment: what do you mean by "referenced by the inner layer pane" ? if we add an instance of `JLayeredPane` in the `content pane`, we can then access it from the `getLayeredPane()` method? or are they completely separated, the instance is located in the content pane, which is located in the layer pane by default, but this instance of `JLayeredPane` is "not" directly contained in the layer pane by default (but in the content pane) ... what is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the first demo (RootLayeredPaneDemo) needs to have access to the layered pane of the frame, whereas the second one (LayeredPaneDemo) doesn't need it.

There's no reason to pass a reference to an object if this reference is not needed.

Comment: thanks JB Nizet, but it's a bit confused to me, do you have any example when you "need" to use the root's layer pane instead of creating a new one?